# Anchor hover and adjacent sibling

Tags: html, css, hover

Imagine this html structure:

```
<p><a></a></p>
<div><a><img></a></div>
```

I want to hide all images inside a `div` after a `p tag`, to do that, I simple use this code:

```
p + div {display:none;}
```

but when I try to show those images by hover the `anchor` inside the `p tag` before, it doesn't work the same way by using this:

```
p > a:hover + div {display:block;}
```

if I use only `p` instead:

```
p:hover + div {display:block;}
```

it works, but it's not what I pretend.

Since `a` it's a child of `p tag`, adjacent sibling "+" doesn't work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Since a it's a child of p tag, adjacent sibling "+" doesn't work?

Correct.  The `div` is a sibling of the `p`, not the `a`.

You could set `pointer-events` for the `p` to "none", and `pointer-events` for the `a` to "auto".

You could then use your working `p:hover + div` code, but it would act like it's working for the anchor only:

```css
p + div {
  display:none;
}

p {
  pointer-events: none;
}

a {
  pointer-events: auto;
}

p:hover + div {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<p>
  <a href="#">This is an anchor.</a> <br>
  Lorem ipsum et cetera.
</p>
<div>
  Cool picture:
  <a>
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/50/50">
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: pointer-events, didn't know it, and it actually works. thanks!